# How to combine arrays from an array returned by MySQL?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array like this, returned by MySQL:

```
array(0 => array('123', 'data'), 1 => array('124', 'data2'));
```

Now I want to transform it into this without doing any loops through an array:

```
array('123' => 'data', '124' => 'data2');
```

Comment: Any particular reason why no loops? Is this homework? or do you just want to make things harder?

Comment: Just for fun. It is easy to use a foreach loop for this, but it is actually boring.

Comment: Just for fun is a motive I can understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = array(0 => array('123', 'data'), 1 => array('124', 'data2'));

$newdata = array_combine( array_map( function( $item ) {
                                         return $item[0];
                                     },
                                     $data
                                   ),
                          array_map( function( $item ) {
                                         return $item[1];
                                     },
                                     $data
                                   )
                        );

var_dump($newdata);
```

Comment: Making trivial tasks look like l33t ;)